# VB.Net Change Windows7 Password Hint

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, passwords

I am creating a Windows Form program that will change specific settings on a newly imaged PC. All of the PCs will be running Windows7 and they are not on any domain. What I need to be able to do is change or remove the password hint for the local account on this PC. If the password hint cannot be changed without changing the password that is OK.

I have code that changes the password but unfortunately it does not change or remove the password hint. I have searched Google and there does not seem to be anything on how to do this.

Comment: I am still looking for the answer to this question.